# Como mudar o nome de multiplos arquivos .mp3 substituindo o primeiro argumento do nome de cada um, por uma ordem sequencial de números

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Imagine que tivéssemos esses arquivos numa pasta:

```
2 arquivoABC.mp3
1 arquivoCBA.mp3
3 arquivoBAC.mp3
0 arquivoBCA.mp3
```

Então, como poderíamos fazer para que os nomes ficassem dessa forma:

```
1 arquivoABC.mp3
2 arquivoCBA.mp3
3 arquivoBAC.mp3
4 arquivoBCA.mp3
```

Como fazer usando batch?

Comment: Qual seria a regra de ordenação que você quer utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

---

Bem vindo a plataforma SO

---

Supondo que as **string** nos nomes **(ABC,CBA,BAC,BCA)** são:

- **Exatamente essas** e **somente essas nessa sequencia**

**1)** Implemente um contador

**2)** liste os **arquivos.mp3** filtra no loop as **strings** na **sequencia desejada**: ABC,CBA,BAC,BCA

**3)** remova os 2 primeiros caráteres

**4)** sete a sequencia desejada

**5)** renomeia

---

**Obs.:** **Edite o comando:** **`Set "_path_mp3=."`**

---

**Substituindo o valor: `"=."` por  `"=drive:\pasta\onde\tem\os\mp3s"`**

**De forma que fique: `set "_path_mp3=drive:\pasta\onde\tem\os\mp3s"`**

---

**`| Reordenar.cmd: |`**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" & set "_path_mp3=." & cd /d "!_path_mp3!" & set /a "_cnt=0"

for %%F in (ABC,CBA,BAC,BCA)do for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('where .:"*.mp3" ^| find /i "%%F"')do (
     set /a "_cnt+=1" && set "_arq_=%%~ni"
     set "_cmd_ren_[!_cnt!]=rename "%%~fi""
     set "_arq_[!_cnt!]=!_arq_:~2,-3!%%F.mp3")

for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do !_cmd_ren_[%%L]! "%%L !_arq_[%%L]!" & where .:"%%L !_arq_[%%L]!" /t
```

---

**`| Resulta: |`**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---